Should I clean oxidation from green copper pipe?
I’ve currently renovating my place and noticed a green spot on the main water line inside my apartment. I’ve did some reading and I suppose it’s oxidation, but I’m not sure if this is severe or a normal occurrence.



Do I need to be worried about leakage and any health concerns?

Should I clean and remove the green oxidised copper? Some sources mention using lemon and salt, whereas others said to use scotch brite. What would be appropriate for this situation?



Also: Is corrosion on copper pipe a concern? and Is this pipe corrosion a problem?

@isherwood the first question linked do not have any pictures to better indicate severity. The second question is about connection of copper to steel in water heater context. This question is solely on copper pipe oxidation.

Fair enough. How about one of these?

I’ve actually seen all of those, believe it or not, and many more from other sites. Most of them looks to have “smudges” of the green oxidised copper in various locations of a common pattern which may or not be acid flux leftover or leakage, too many conflicting opinions. In my context, it’s only this one location in the entire apartment. Opinions also varied on whether to leave it or clean it up. Hence, I’ve posed this question specific to this context.

It is "apartment" that makes this quite iffy to do yourself.  It might take you five seconds to clean it yourself, but there is always that 1 in 1000 chance of oops and in apartments, that can become nasty.

@crip659 thanks for the feedback. My apartment management said that anything past my main door is going to be self managed. So I’m going to try to clean it up with some scotch brite and hope I don’t observe any leaks.

Is the "apartment" a dwelling you own, or rent?

@Huesmann this is in Singapore. It is a condo that I own but with management for the complex.

@Wayne then it's probably your responsibility (IDK Singapore rules, except that there seem to be a lot of them).

I would not use anything harsh. You coukd damage the solder. Since its at the join, I  suspect you may have a tiny tiny leak there.
If it bothers you, clean it with some weak acidic compound. But I woukd get a plumber to have a look at it.
